# Listing AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Please help in finding the mistake, or propose another way to do the following:

I'm trying to show the list of `AspNetUsers` into a `ListView` and then show the list of its `AspNetRoles` by using a nested `ListView`:

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ItemType= "CEODAL.AspNetUser" SelectMethod="GetAspNetUsers" >
<LayoutTemplate>
    <h4>Registered Users</h4>
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder"></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td><%#: Item.UserName %></td>
        <td>
            <asp:ListView ID="Repeater1" runat="server" ItemType="CEODAL.AspNetRole" SelectMethod="<%#: Item.AspNetRoles.ToList() %>">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <h4>Registered Users</h4>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder2"></tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <%#: Item.Name %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

The `SelectMethod` of the parent `ListView` will simply return the list of the `AspNetUsers`:

```
return _db.AspNetUsers.ToList();
```

Without the child `ListView`, everything is working fine, where I will get the list of usernames.

Once I put the second `ListView` I will get the following error:

> A public method with the name 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[CEODAL.AspNetRole]' was either not found or there were multiple methods with the same name on the type 'ASP.pages_manageusers_aspx'.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the attribute

```
SelectMethod="<%#: Item.AspNetRoles.ToList() %>">
```

in your inner ListView with

```
DataSource="<%# Item.AspNetRoles.ToList() %>">
```

You are getting an error because the [`SelectMethod`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.databoundcontrol.selectmethod(v=vs.110).aspx) property has a string value (the name of the codebehind method to call) and you are passing it an ObservableCollection of role objects.  Clearly you codebehind class has no method whose name is the result of converting a collection to a string, hence your error

Comment: Ok. I'm getting the error: The 'DataSource' property cannot be set declaratively.

Comment: Odd, I don't get that error.  I get that error if I write the attribute as `DataSource="Item.AspNetRoles.ToList()"`, i.e. without the `<%# ... %>`, data-binding tags.